# Pause and resume repeatable NSTimer when closing and opening window

Tags: objective-c, nstimer, nstableview, nswindow, awakefromnib

Now I know there are questions on SO about NSTimer pause, but none on repeatable and closing/opening windows.
Toggeling pause works perfect (checked using button).
Reopening window gives BAD_ACCESS error.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.timer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.85
                                               target:self
                                             selector:@selector(populateTable:)
                                             userInfo:nil
                                              repeats:YES] retain];
}

-(IBAction)fireUpTableWindow:(id)sender
{
    [aTableWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
    [self resumeTimer:timer];
}


NSDate *pauseStart, *previousFireDate;

-(void) pauseTimer:timer
{
    pauseStart = [[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0] retain];    
    previousFireDate = [[timer fireDate] retain];
    [timer setFireDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
}

-(void) resumeTimer:timer
{
    float pauseTime = -1*[pauseStart timeIntervalSinceNow];
    [timer setFireDate:[previousFireDate initWithTimeInterval:pauseTime sinceDate:previousFireDate]];
    [pauseStart release];
    [previousFireDate release];
}

- (IBAction)closeTableWindow:(id)sender
{
    [self pauseTimer:timer];
    [self->aTableWindow close];
    [self release];
}
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't put retain on your timer..thats only going to cause problems

Comment: @ttarules still got the same error without retaining the timer... and I did try [timer invalidate] at closeTableWindow as well, didn't work sadly...

Comment: @ttarules and I also tried to with deleting all retaining (also in resumeTimer etc.)

Comment: Also it uses: - (void) dealloc { [timer invalidate]; [timer release]; timer = nil; [super dealloc]; }  And I was thinking of creating entire new timer after invalidating it at closeTableWindow...

Comment: In header file: @property (assign) NSTimer *timer;

Comment: There's nothing wrong with retaining a timer, @ttarules, provided that you release it appropriately.

Comment: _Reopening window gives BAD_ACCESS error._ Check in Interface Builder that the Window is not set to _Release on close_.

Comment: @GerdK this is it! That makes it work, strange lol. Can you make this an answer, I could then mark it as answered, thanks so much.

Comment: @Jeremiah Smith:  Thanks, done. Glad it worked out, I have fallen for this one  before hence it rang a bell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Reopening window gives BAD_ACCESS error.

Check in Interface Builder that the Window is not set to *Release on Close*.